# chosen-select mutliple select update from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jquery-chosen

I'm using the chosen plugin for a multiple select. I want to retrieve the customer pre-selected values from the database and display them in the multiple select when i return the rest of the data.

The following code works fine:

```
$('.chosen-select').val(["Test1", "Test2"]).trigger('chosen:updated');
```

However when I try and put a variable in there like below, it doesn't populate the values.

```
$('.chosen-select').val([res]).trigger('chosen:updated');
```

I've pulled the data out and I then loop through the array and store it in a variable. I've checked the contents of the `res` variable and it's correct, so now I'd like to reference it within the square brackets but it doesn't work, and it doesn't throw any errors. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
        var i;
        var res = ""; 

        for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

            array[i] = $.trim(array[i]);
            var buildValue2 = '"' + array[i] + '", ';
            if (i == array.length - 1) {
                /* this is the last one so no comma*/
                buildValue2 = '"' + array[i] + '"';
            }
            res = res.concat(buildValue2);

        }

        alert(res);

        $('.chosen-select').val([res]).trigger('chosen:updated');
```

Comment: val expects array, so try with res=[]; res.push(buildValue2);

Comment: put array instead of String.

Comment: try: `$('.chosen-select').val(array).trigger('chosen:updated'); `

Comment: @benG that worked! Thank you!! If you put that as an answer I'll mark it as correct :D

Comment: @jare25 thanks for the info on it expecting an array - makes total sense now :)

Comment: :) did not look what are you doing with array, but after benG's answer I saw that you already have array, and you tried to create string from array, to create an array from string... :)

Comment: @jare25 - yeah very messy - I got myself all tied up in knots!